# Adding foreach to codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a view where the user will input invoice line items.  When they click submit the data is sent to my controller in an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [amount] => Array
        (
            [0] => 130.00
            [1] => 50.00
        )

    [quantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.00
            [1] => 1.00
        )

    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

    [work_description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Programming: 
            [1] => Design:
        )
)
```

Now I need to loop through each one to add it to the database via the model.  Not sure if I should use `foreach` or build an empty array and use `array merge`?

The desired result will iterate through each array, and add to the database.  So `amount[0]`, `quantity[0]`, `item[0]`, `work_description[0]`, and then on to the next set of keys.

```
//needs to be foreach or build array?
$items = array(
    'invoice_id' => $prefix_invoices_id,
    'amount' => $this->input->post('amount'),
    'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),
    'item' => $this->input->post('item'),
    'work_description' => $this->input->post('work_description'),
    'taxable' => $this->input->post('taxable'),
);

$this->load->model('Invoice_item_model');
$prefix_invoice_lines = $this->Invoice_item_model->add_prefix_invoice_items($items);
```

And my view in case it helps (user has ability to clone rows to add more line items so it will usually come in as an array):

```
<tbody>
  <tr class="tr_clone" id="inv_line_1">
    <td>
        <select id="line_item_1" name="item[]" class="invoice_line_item">
            <option></option>
            <?php
    foreach($prefix_line_items as $line_item)
    {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $line_item['id']; ?>"><?php echo $line_item['item']; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" id="description_1" name="work_description[]" class="description" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="currency" id="amount_1" name="amount[]" class="amount" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="number" id="quantity_1" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="" /></td>
    <td><input type="currency" id="price_1" name="price[]" class="price" value=""  readonly/></td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="add-line-item"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>   <a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="remove-line-item"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = array(
    'amount' => array(
        0 => 130.00, 
        1 => 50.00
    ),
    'quantity' => array(
        0 => 1,
        1 => 1
    ),
    'item' => array(
        0 => 3,
        1 => 4
    ),
    'work_description' => array(
        0 => 'Programing: ',
        1 => 'Design: '
    )
);

$insert = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['item']); $i++)
{
    $insert[$i] = array('amount' => $array['amount'][$i], 'quantity' => $array['quantity'][$i], 'item' => $array['item'][$i], 'work_description' => $array['work_description'][$i]); // $insert is ready for insert_batch
}
//var_dump($insert);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, all I can think of is this combiner:

```
function add_prefix_invoice_items($items = array) {
    $rows = [];
    $keys = ['amount', 'quantity', 'item', 'work_description', 'taxable'];
    $total_keys = count($keys);
    $all = $items[$keys[0]];

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++) {
        $values = [];
        for ($j = 0; $j < $total_keys; $j++)
            $values[] = $items[$keys[$j]][$i]; // fetch next row

        $row = array_combine($keys, $values); // combine key => value pairs

        // can insert row ('amount' => nnn, 'quantity' => nnn, ...) into the database now
        $id = ...

        $rows[$id] = $row
    }

    return $rows;
}
```